# JS - parsing data with random single quotes

Tags: javascript, parsing

How do I parse an array of objects if it contains single quote characters?

For example, I have:

```
$example = '{"response":[{"uid":3202935,"first_name":"Martha","last_name":"O'Nill","user_id":3202935},{"uid":4070530,"first_name":"Alex","last_name":"White","user_id":4070530}]}';
```

The single quotes seem to break up the array, making parsing impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `backticks` (**``**). It will generate the string as it was written, with double `""` and single `'` quotes.

```js
var str = `{"response":[{"uid":3202935,"first_name":"Martha","last_name":"O'Nill","user_id":3202935},{"uid":4070530,"first_name":"Alex","last_name":"White","user_id":4070530}]}`;
console.log(str);

var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj.response[0].uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a json string not an object.

Use `JSON.parse(myJsonSting)` and you will get objects with the `'` taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is supposed to ignore single quotes if it is inside double quotes, in your case try adding backslash before the single quote.

Answer (score 0):

To parse at json string to object

```
var example = '{"response":[{"uid":3202935,"first_name":"Martha","last_name":"O'Nill","user_id":3202935},{"uid":4070530,"first_name":"Alex","last_name":"White","user_id":4070530}]}';
var objExample = JSON.parse(example);
```

To convert json object to json string

```
var StrExample  = JSON.stringify(objExample);
```